How to ensure that two divs remain the same height using CSS?
I'm working on a project and I'm having some issues. Here's a quick explanation:
I have 3 divs: "feed-container" (FC), "feed-post"(FP) and "comments-section"(CS). The last 2 are contained inside the first one. My goal is to have FP and CS next to each other, separated by a small gap and that both are the same height (taking the height of FP as the max height). I'll link a screenshot of where I'm at for now Screenshot of the page. Don't mind the colours, they're here for me to better visualize my containers haha. So from the image, my tallest div is CS. It's basically a div that stretches as more content is added to it via a form. The FP div is a fixed height that is defined by the size of the picture inside of it. I need CS to have a max height that is equal to the height of FP and any content that need to be added and that can't fit should be accessible via a scrollbar on the div.
(Edit): To give more information about my code, the container "comment-section", which needs to be resized to fit the container "feed-post", also contains 2 other containers, "comment-form" which is a text area alongside a submit button and "comment-box" which contains the profile picture, date and time and the comment of the person that submitted something in comment-form. Each time a new comment is added, a new "comment-box" is added. To go back on the screenshot I sent, each comment box is in aquamarine blue. The comment-form container is colored in wheat (beige) and the comment-section (colored in mediumslateblue) englobes these 2.
Here is the CSS of all my containers:
.feed-container {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.feed-post {
    background-color: orange;
    min-width: 49%;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.comments-section {
    background-color:mediumslateblue;
    min-width: 49%;
    max-width: 49%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.comment-form {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.comment-box {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Attribut suivant à enlever. Aide juste à la visualisation */
}

I'm unsure about what to add/remove in order for the last container to match the height of the second one. If anyone can help, I'll gladly listen !
I've tried asking GPT about it and he gave me a bunch of stuff to try. The most relevant one I think seems to be adding "max-height: 100%" to CS alongside "max-height: max-content;" for FP. Sadly, it didn't fix my issue.
.feed-container {
    background-color: pink;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.feed-post {
    background-color: orange;
    min-width: 49%;
    margin-right: 1em;
    max-height: max-content;
}

.comments-section {
    background-color:mediumslateblue;
    min-width: 49%;
    max-width: 49%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do read on How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example for us to help you out better

You can achieve this by creating an inner container and making it absolute which will be relative to the comment-section. Your code should look like this . You can use display: flex also for this and set individual widths for both containers


.feed-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
  background-color: pink;
}

.feed-post {
  background-color: orange;
}

.comment-section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
}

.comment-content {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
<div class="feed-container">
  <div class="feed-post">
    <p>Images: is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-section">
    <div class="comment-content">
      <p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for your answer. I'm still having some issues but it's normal as I didn't show the full code. It's a bit complex since it's not my code but the code of someone else in my group project and I've been asked to do the CSS for it. The container "comment-section" has 2 other containers inside of it. It has "comment-form" which contains a text area and a submit button and under that there is "comment-box" which has the profile picture, date and time and comment of the person that submitted a comment. Every time there is a new comment, there is a new "comment-box" inside "comment-section".

I would advise you to edit your question to show the HTML structure and the CSS, just the containers with classes would suffice, you don't need to write the whole code. But if I understand your question you have 2 other (divs) container in the comment-section; if this is the case, you need to move the 2 containers inside the comment-content because that's where the absolute style is implemented

You can solve this by using two different CSS properties: FlexBox or Grids.
Here you have an example: https://codepen.io/faridsilva/pen/wvVEwJJ
Using Flexbox:
<section class="feed-container">
   <div class="feed-post">
      This is the feed post
   </div>
   <div class="comments-section">
      This is the comments section
   </div>
</section>

.feed-container {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  gap: 2%;
}

.feed-post {
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  flex-shrink: 1; // column can shrink at same speed
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 49%; // limit to maker room for 2 columns
}

.comments-section {
  background-color: mediumslateblue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;// column can shrink at same speed
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 49%;// limit to maker room for 2 columns
}

Using CSS Grid
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Column 1</div>
  <div class="item">Column 2</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* Two columns at 50% each */
  gap: 20px; /* Adjust the gap size as needed */
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightgrey; /* Example styling for items */
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


Your Flexbox approach is sloppy. But your approaches miss the actual question. The question is not just how to size both boxes at the same height but to the height if the first column. Both your "solutions" size it according to the highest box.

Thanks for your answer. Sadly, it didn't really fix my issues. The 2 elements didn't shrink to the same size and instead it just centered the contents of the containers.
